# RuntimeIdentifiers and SelfContained

Tags: .net-core

I have set both `RuntimeIdentifiers` and `SelfContained` as below

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

it failed with

> It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application
> without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier.  Please either specify a
> RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false.  UBS.Service
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets   133

But according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#runtimeidentifiers). The `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` property element lets you specify a semicolon-delimited list of Runtime Identifiers (RIDs) for the project. RIDs enable publishing self-contained deployments.

**Am I missing something?  or the document is wrong?**

**UPDATE**: To work around this issue, I am using `RuntimeIdentifier` and `SelfContained` as below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <RuntimeIdentifier Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Unix' ">linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: How are you building?

Comment: @ESG using Visual Studio

Comment: Are you setting <SelfContained> in the csproj? as that won't work. self contained is a publishing step, that is either included in a publishing profile, or passed as a build argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Comment: @CodedBeard  but `<RuntimeIdentifier>` and `<SelfContained>` works fine in csproj

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor IS this needs to be added to every project in solution or only the startup project?